# Why is field hockey played with water on the field?

Tags: field-hockey

In the recently held Champions Trophy, I saw that the players play with water on the field.

[image: Water at the foot of the player]

Why is water present on the field?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The game was being played on artificial turf. According to Wikipedia:

> There are three main types of artificial hockey surface:
>  
>    - **Unfilled or water-based** – artificial fibres that are densely packed    for stabilisation, requires irrigation or watering to avoid
>   pitch    wear
>    - **Dressed or sand-dressed** – artificial fibres can be less densely    packed and sand supports the fibres for part of the pile depth
>    - **Filled or sand-filled** – artificial fibres can be longer and less    densely packed and sand supports the fibres for 100% of the
>   pile    depth

The purpose of water is:

> On water-based pitches, shorter fibres and wetted turf reduce friction and increase the speed at which the game can be played.

The article also states:

> Elite-level competitions, such as the Olympic Games and World Cup, require a water-based playing surface.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_hockey_pitch#Artificial_playing_surface